# How to change the GUI of transmission web interface?

Tags: transmission

I'am talking about this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo
I see this web interface: http://92.245.108.213:9091/transmission/web

where are stored the html files of this web interface? is it possible to edit it?

Comment: eh provide us the username and password to that link please. We can not access that link.

Comment: @Rinzwind that is a pseudo-link, I am talking about this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this as a generic solution:

```
sudo find / -name 'web' -type d 2>/dev/null| grep 'transmission/web'
```

This is the default directory:

```
/usr/local/transmission/share/transmission/web/
```

---

I found this [Web GUI alternative for a combined browser and mobile version](https://github.com/ronggang/transmission-web-control) and it uses this [script](https://github.com/ronggang/transmission-web-control/blob/master/release/install-tr-control.sh) to change the interface (see line 37 and 46). If it does not find it, the script then uses the command posted above.

So you can use that as a generic solution.

Comment: For me the default directory was `/usr/share/transmission/web/` (Linux Mint 21.x)